# Translation of "just" for recent past

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, adverbes

"I just saw Sue yesterday/last week."

How can we translation this, especially the word "just"? Can it be translated directly with *juste*?

> J'ai juste vu Sue hier/la semaine dernière.

Or should we use *venir+de*? I'm not sure if it should only be used for more recent past like an hour ago?

> Je viens de voir Sue hier/la semaine dernière.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Juste](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/juste)* has several functions (adjective, adverb, noun) and meanings. Here it can be used to mean *seulement* or *précisément*.

- *Juste* might mean *seulement* et *exactement* (only and precisely):

> Je l'ai vue juste hier / juste la semaine dernière. (colloquial)
>
> Je n'ai vu Sue qu'hier / que la semaine dernière. (i.e. I didn't saw her before or after).

- You can also use *juste* to mean the event happened in the very close past, almost the present:

> Je viens juste de voir Sue.

You cannot use the same expression if the event is older. In this context, one day or one week are not compatible with *venir juste*.

Comment: Can "juste" in "Je l'ai vue juste hier / juste la semaine dernière" mean "recently" instead of "precisely/only"?

Comment: That's very unlikely.

Comment: Is there anyway to say "I just saw Sue yesterday", putting the emphasis that I saw her recently?

Comment: *J'ai vu Sue pas plus tard qu'hier !* PS: Sue is an extremely rare first name in France.

Answer (score 1):

I would totally skip the 'just/juste in both English and French'.

*I saw Sue yesterday/last week.*

*J'ai vu Sue hier/la semaine dernière.*

Just/juste are not really formal.

Comment: Exactly. Does it really make sense to use "just" if it's yesterday, or last week ? I know it's idiomatic, but it's really not necessary so it's dropped in French. "*J'ai vu Sue hier/la semaine dernière*" means exactly what you want.